# Код для секундомера не начинает отчет при нажатии кнопки "Старт"

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtimer

Код для секундомера Python (3.9, PyQT5), не начинает отчет при нажатии.
Укажите пожалуйста на ошибки, что у меня не так?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/AIR/Downloads/watch.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.StartButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.StartButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 151, 71))
        self.StartButton.setObjectName("StartButton")
        self.ResetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.ResetButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 30, 151, 71))
        self.ResetButton.setObjectName("ResetButton")
        self.Time = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.Time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 140, 321, 121))
        self.Time.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.Time.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Time.setReadOnly(True)
        self.Time.setObjectName("Time")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Sekundomer"))
        self.StartButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Старт"))
        self.ResetButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Стоп/Сброс"))
        self.Time.setText(_translate("Dialog", "00:00:00"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def start():
    global isStart, startTime

    isStart = True
    startTime = time.time()

def reset():
    global isStart, startTime

    isStart = False

def timerFunction():
    global isStart, startTime

    if isStart:
        time_r = int(time.time() - startTime)

        hours = time_r // 3600
        minutes = (time_r % 3600)//60
        seconds = time_r % 60

        if hours > 99:
            isStart = False

        else:
            hours = str(hours)
            minutes = str(minutes)
            seconds = str(seconds)

            time_str = '0'*(2-len(hours))+hours+":"+"0"*(2-len(minutes))+minutes+":"+"0"*(2-len(seconds))+seconds

            Sekundomer.Time.setText(time_str)

Sekundomer.StartButton.clicked.connect(start)
Sekundomer.ResetButton.clicked.connect(reset)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(timerFunction)
timer.start(100)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: У вас `Sekundomer.StartButton.clicked.connect(start)` - посмотрите что делает функция `start` Там просто присваивается значение переменной

Comment: @SergBocharov таймер уже запущен ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Глобальные переменные - это зло!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/AIR/Downloads/watch.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.StartButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.StartButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 151, 71))
        self.StartButton.setObjectName("StartButton")
        self.ResetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.ResetButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 30, 151, 71))
        self.ResetButton.setObjectName("ResetButton")
        self.Time = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.Time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 140, 321, 121))
        self.Time.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.Time.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Time.setReadOnly(True)
        self.Time.setObjectName("Time")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Sekundomer"))
        self.StartButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Старт"))
        self.ResetButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Стоп/Сброс"))
        self.Time.setText(_translate("Dialog", "00:00:00"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.StartButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.ResetButton.clicked.connect(self.reset)

        self.isStart = False
        self.startTime = ...

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerFunction)
        self.timer.start(100)   

    def start(self):
        self.isStart = True
        self.startTime = time.time()

    def reset(self):
        self.isStart = False

    def timerFunction(self):
        if self.isStart:
            time_r = int(time.time() - self.startTime)
            hours = time_r // 3600
            minutes = (time_r % 3600)//60
            seconds = time_r % 60

            if hours > 99:
                self.isStart = False
            else:
                hours = str(hours)
                minutes = str(minutes)
                seconds = str(seconds)
                time_str = '0'*(2-len(hours)) + hours+":"+"0"*(2-len(minutes)) + \
                    minutes+":"+"0"*(2-len(seconds)) + seconds
                self.Time.setText(time_str)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]